# Some calculation in Cahn-Hilliard euqation

Tags: functional-analysis

My question comes from paper(https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/17M1150153).

Given an energy functional $E(\phi)$,  denote its variational derivative as $ u = \dfrac{\delta E}{\delta \phi} $. Then the gradient flow can be written as
$ \begin{equation}
\qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t } = \mathcal{G} u 
\end{equation}，
$

where $\mathcal{G}$ is a non-positive symmetric operator. Then we have

> $ \dfrac{\text{d}E(\phi)}{\text{d}t} = \dfrac{\delta E}{\delta \phi}
> \cdot \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = (u , \mathcal{G}u) \leqslant 0 , \qquad \qquad $
> where ***$(\phi , \psi) = \int \phi \psi \text{d}x $***.

---

My question is : Let $ E = \int |\nabla \phi\ |^2 \text{d}x$ , then left hand of above is

> $\dfrac{\text{d}E(\phi)}{\text{d}t} = -2\int \Delta \phi \phi_t \text{d}x $

right hand of above is

> $ \dfrac{\delta E}{\delta \phi}
> \cdot \dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}  = -2\Delta \phi \cdot \phi _t$

so, where the integral of right hand comes from?